# How to host React Js project using AWS ec2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, host

I want to host my react js project using AWS ec2. without cloning my GitHub repo. how to do that?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You will need another machine that would run:

```
npm run build
```

to build your react js project. After compiling it, you will have to transfer the files via `scp`:

```sh
scp -i "yourkey.pem" -r ec2user@DNS_name:/var/www/html ./my-react-app-folder/dist
```

I would recommend looking into using Amazon S3 & CloudFront combination to host your website though! Its' the modern way of hosting websites using serverless architecture that allows us to save resources and add caching on static assets and save precious electricy!